# Incorporating External Html into a jQuery Mobile page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, load, external, inject

I am attempting to dynamically incorporate an external source of html into a jQuery mobile page. I am able to successfully incorporate the external html but it looks like regular HTML (i.e. not jQuery mobile affected Html). Can any one suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Main Html:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"
    />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#main").load('externalHtml.html');
            //$("#main").append('externalHtml.html');
            //$("#main").load('externalHtml.html #contain');
            //$("#main").page();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="main"></div>Main Page</div>
</body>
```

externalHtml.html:

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
external html
<div data-role="content" id="contain">
<input  type="search" name="name" id="name" value="" />
 </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you `.trigger('create')` on the container element, jQuery Mobile will automatically initialize any widget within the container. For example:

```
$("#main").load('externalHtml.html').trigger('create');
```

They really should document this better, but if you look at the API events for each type of widget, you will see the documentation regarding the `create` event.

Also, read the top of this page of the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

You should not be using `document.ready` and instead should be binding to the `pageinit` event for pseudo-pages. Using `document.ready` will most likely create headaches for you in the future.

**-- UPDATE --**

You will probably want to call `.trigger('create')` in a callback so the external HTML has loaded before you attempt to initialize it:

```
$("#main").load('externalHtml.html', function () {
    $(this).trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: @Magico You can use `window.location.hash = 'some-hash';` to update the URL, or in modern browsers you can use the pushState API to update the URL beyond the hash.